# Create a Heatmap for findAssocs results based on time

Tags: r, nlp, heatmap, correlation, tm

I have the following data for which I create a document-term matrix first and then I add the time variable to the dtm. In order to see the correlations to the term "updat" in the different years, I would like to have a heat-map for findAssoc in a way that x-axis shows the time.

```
library(tm) 
library(ggplot2)

df <- structure(list(Description = structure(c(5L, 8L, 6L, 4L, 1L,
2L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 3L), .Label = c("general topics done", "keep the general topics updated",
 "rejected topic ", "several topics in hand", "this is a genetal topic",
 "topic 333555 needs to be updated", "topic 5647 is handed over",
 "topic is updated", "update the topic ", "updating the topic is done "
  ), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,
  -10L))
corpus=Corpus(VectorSource(df$Description))
corpus=tm_map(corpus,tolower)
corpus=tm_map(corpus,removePunctuation)
corpus=tm_map(corpus,removeWords,c(stopwords("english")))
corpus=tm_map(corpus,stemDocument,"english")

frequenciescontrol=DocumentTermMatrix(corpus)
frequenciescontrol$time=c("2015","2015","2015","2015","2015","2016","2016","2016","2016","2016")
findAssocs(frequenciescontrol, "updat", 0.01)
```

So I want a heatmap with y axis showing the words correlated to "updat" and x axis showing the years.